# Similar Form authentication in OWIN MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, form-authentication

I am taking over from another colleague where he has implemented OWIN in the project. Now what I am trying to achieve is to add a login method and see if the user is logged in then add the authentication like we used to do in form authentication like this

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true);
```

What I am trying to achieve overall is this function

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(String email, String password)
    {
        //  Request.GetOwinConte

        // TODO validate user
        /*
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(email, password))
        {


        }*/

        //var user = UserManager.FindAsync(email, password);

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, true); // how should I replicate this in OWIN?
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Site");

    }
```

So after following the links in the comments and this tutorial
http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux#disqus_thread

I have been able to store cookies like this

```
    public ActionResult Login(String email, String password)
    {
        //  Request.GetOwinConte

        // TODO validate user
        /*
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(email, password))
        {

        }*/

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email),
                    },
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = true
        }, identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Site");

    }
```

Can someone explain what does this identity variable has? And how do I check the user credentials? That even he is the right person or not?

Comment: Has he used ASP.NET Identity? You can learn about it at http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity and about OWIN at http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana

Comment: Yep. Identity is being used. It replaces and supersedes ASP.NET Membership (Forms Auth). Read the docs and you should be fine.